# Ajax pass parameter in data send to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Let's suppose i have a element with a onclick function on it which trigger a prompt() when clicked.
once the user fill the prompt, it also trigger a ajax request that will send the prompt value with the post type to a php page to get a response.

so i have this code:

```
<i class="fas fa-wrench text-warning editmode" id="Pseudo" onclick="goEdit(this.id)" title="Edit my pseudo"></i>

function goEdit(id) {
        console.log(id); // The console log here print me "Pseudo" and that's what i want
        $(document).ready(function() {
            let userchange = prompt();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'traitements/traitement-profil.php',
                data: {
                    id: userchange

// The problem is here ! I want to send a $_POST['Pseudo'] that contains the answer of the prompt. 
// But that doesn't work.
// Instead if i a do a print($_POST) in my php page i get this as a response in my alert below:
// array(1) { ["id"]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(24) "Answer of the prompt here"

                },
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

The reason why i need my $_POST to be equal to the value of the id of the button clicked is because i need multiple buttons like this one on the same page and every one of them will have it's own purpose but will always do kind of the same thing. Only the $_post parameter will change for each and this parameter has to be equal to the id of the button clicked

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** If what you want is a dynamic key in your data object you can achieve it the following way:

```
var data = {};
data[id] = userchange;

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'traitements/traitement-profil.php',
   data: data,
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
   }
});
```

---

It seems that you misunderstood how to structure a [JSON object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp).

The data you pass shall look like this:

```
data: {
   id: id,
   answer: userchange
},
```

Then in PHP you will be able to access them the following way:

```
 $_POST['id'] // contains "Pseudo"
 $_POST['answer'] // contains "Answer of the prompt here"
```

Comment: That's not what i want. I want the parameter of $_POST the be equal to the id of my button and containing the answer of the prompt

Comment: Ahh I see, sorry then i misunderstood. Check the updated answer :)

Comment: kind of works but everything in php is contained in a double array like this : array(1) { ["data"]=>array(1) { ["Pseudo"]=> string(4) "Answer of the prompt"  } }
Is there a way to just get everything in a single array without the "data" array ?
And if not, how can i access the ["pseudo"] and answer separately within the array ["data"] ?

Comment: Nevermind ! There was something wrong in the syntax. works perfectly now :)